# Manipulate multidimensional array with php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
$arr = array(
           array("2014-03-13"=>array("a"=>1,"b"=>2)),
           array("2014-03-12"=>array("a"=>4,"b"=>3))
       );
```

And I would like the change the way it looks to something more like this.

```
$arr = array(0=>array("date"=>"2014-03-13","a"=>1,"b"=>2),
             1=>array("date"=>"2014-03-12","a"=>4,"b"=>3));
```

Heres what I have so far.

```
$keys = array();
$vals = array();
foreach($arr as $row){
   foreach($row as $key=>$val){
     $keys[]=array("date"=>$key);
     foreach($val as $keys=>$values){
        $vals[]=array($keys=>$values);
     }
   }
}
```

The `array` which gets the `dates` works fine so in the below example the `$keys array` works however the `$vals array` does not work as intended and instead gives me an array similar to this.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [a] => 1 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [b] => 2 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [a] => 4 ) 
        [3] => Array ( [b] => 3 ) 
        [4] => Array ( [a] => 4 ) 
        [5] => Array ( [b] => 3 ) )
```

Any help to get the array desired is appreciated.

Comment: In that first array there is a 0=>, but shouldn't there also be a 1=>?

Comment: @IarsAnders No there shouldn't and really its irrelevant if it wasn't there the array still prints out the same way.

Comment: Or, preferably, be no `0=>` at all as numeric indexes are implicit in php.

Comment: Ill remove it sorry. Its just how the array was given to me so I kept it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
$result = array();
foreach($arr as $row) {
    foreach($row as $date=>$values) {
        $values['date'] = $date;
        $result[] = $values;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        "2014-03-13" => array("a"=>1, "b"=>2)
    ),
    array(
        "2014-03-12" => array("a"=>4, "b"=>3)
    ),
);


$result = array();
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $date => $values) {
        $result[] = array_merge(array('date' => $date), $values);
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Here is the code:

   $arr = array(
         0=>array("2014-03-13"=>array("a"=>1,"b"=>2)),
           array("2014-03-12"=>array("a"=>4,"b"=>3))
       );

$finalarray=array();
foreach($arr as $k=>$v){    

    foreach($v as $kk=>$vv){
        $newarray=array();

        $newarray["date"]=$kk;
        foreach($vv as $kkk=>$vvv){
            $newarray[$kkk]=$vvv;

        }


    }

    $finalarray[]=$newarray;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($finalarray);
echo "</pre>";

        **Here is the output:**

        Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2014-03-13
                    [a] => 1
                    [b] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2014-03-12
                    [a] => 4
                    [b] => 3
                )

        )
```